# array.push is not working titanium appecelrator

Tags: javascript, titanium-alloy

I am not able to submit/post my data when I am trying to add a specific entry using the push method.

I have the following code

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};
var TF;
var TA;
var basicSwitch;
var caViewBoolean;
var bounded_field;
var caViewDistance;
var commentTA;
var pinTF;
var newTF = [];
var issueTABoolean;
var correctTABoolean;
var issueTADistance;
var correctTADistance;
var mFields = [];
var isRequire = [];
var bounded_lblTitle = [];
var postButton;

$.scrView.customName = "New Entry";

if (args.fromLog == "Yes") {
    Alloy.Globals.logViews.push($.scrView);
    Alloy.Globals.logScrollableView.views = Alloy.Globals.logViews;
    Alloy.Globals.logScrollableView.scrollToView($.scrView);
} else {
    Alloy.Globals.locationViews.push($.scrView);
    Alloy.Globals.locationScrollableView.views = Alloy.Globals.locationViews;
    Alloy.Globals.locationScrollableView.scrollToView($.scrView);
}

//Click event of New Entry button
function onbtnClick() {

    if (OS_ANDROID) {
        Alloy.Globals.buttonClickEffect(postButton);
    }

    var mFields = [];

    //Create data which will be used to create new entry
    if (TF) {
        var tf_dict = {
            "id": TF._id,
            "value": TF.value
        };
        mFields.push(tf_dict);
    }

    if (TA) {
        var ta_dict = {
            "id": TA._id,
            "value": TA.value
        };
        mFields.push(ta_dict);
    }
    var boolean_dict = [i];
    for (var k = 0; k < yesnobasicswitch.length; k++) {
        if (yesnobasicswitch[i]) {
            if (yesnobasicswitch[i].value) {
                boolean_dict[i] = {
                    "id": yesnobasicswitch[i]._id,
                    "value": yesnobasicswitch[i].value,
                    "ca": {
                        "problem": issuetextarea[i].value,
                        "solution": correctivetextarea[i].value
                    }
                };
            } else {
                boolean_dict[i] = {
                    "id": yesnobasicswitch[i]._id,
                    "value": yesnobasicswitch[i].value
                };
            }

            mFields.push(boolean_dict[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure If the code is enough to make people understand what I am trying to do. The code has been written by someone else and it is just a part of it.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting in console?

Comment: That code is almost painful to read. The magic variables, naming and general flow makes it very difficult to decipher. I feel sorry for you, mate. It would, however, help if you could hilight the line that you added (the push) and also give us the error you are getting.

Comment: console gives me http://pastebin.com/pd3NZmW4  @Mithun

I understand your concern Nenotlep

Basically, I create a form which has couple of text fields, checkboxes and when the checkbox is checked another text fields shows up, we input value and we submit, on submitting, nothing happens and have mentioned the console thing above in pastebin

Comment: My suggestion would be like check whether the dynamic creation is binding in the page, inspect the element and have breakpoints where exactly its failing. Onclick or before... hope that would help atleast a bit

Comment: everything seems working and as expected, I can not do inspect element here, Its an app running on the emulator. Only issue is when I click submit, the above thing I get in the console